# Wordpress broken,cannot access admin, tried to change themes

Tags: php, wordpress

Okay I have a big problem here. I am trying to upgrade to wp 3.5.1 and it is not working. So one of the suggestions was to switch to the default theme. Which I did, and that did not work. Now I have switched back to the genesis theme we use and I get this:

```
Warning: require_once(/example/wp-content/themes/child/lib/init.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /example/wp-content/themes/child/functions.php on line 16

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/example/wp-content/themes/child/lib/init.php' (include_path='.:/example/lib/php') in /example/wp-content/themes/child/functions.php on line 16
```

I tried reverting to a backup from yesterday and this is all still broken. Can anyone point me in the right direction here? I don't understand this genesis theme/child relationship very well and frankly I have no idea what is happening here.

Luckily I have backups of everything but I can't seem to get everything working again after trying the theme switch.

Comment: What did you revert? PHP files? Database? Both?

Comment: I reverted the PHP files

Comment: Ok. So what you have now is a database that was (potentially) updated to 3.5.1, whether successfully or unsuccessfully, but you have pre-3.5.1 code running on it. Do you have a database backup?

Comment: ahh, but you see the update to 3.5.1 never occurred. I am back in now and the errors or gone, I had to change wp_options stylesheet from "child" to "Genesis" And back to square one of not being able to use the automatic update feature to get 3.5.1, keep getting an "installation failed" error

Comment: That last comment suggests that you've solved this? Is that right?

Comment: yes, this particular issue is solved...do I update with my own answer?

Comment: You can answer your own question, yes, and I believe that you are encouraged to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Changing wp_options value "stylesheet" to "genesis" from "child" fixed my issue. So that change must not have been executed properly when reverting back to the Genesis theme, or at least the db was not updated in the way we needed for our particular install.